# Вытащить картинку из БД

Tags: php

Необходимо вытащить картинку из БД, в БД хранится имя картинки, а сами файлы находятся в папке на хостинге, как мне достать картинку? Данным кодом сохраняю:

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $sesion_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $idf = ($_SESSION['userid']);

if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
if(empty($_FILES['file']['size']))  die('Вы не выбрали файл');
if($_FILES['file']['size'] > (5 * 1024 * 1024)) die('image size <5mb');
$imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$arr = array('image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png');
if(!in_array($imageinfo['mime'],$arr)) echo ('image format');
 else {

$upload_dir = '/public_html/'; 
$name = date('YmdHis').basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

$mov = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$name);
  if($mov) {

$name = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($name)));
 if(!$mysqli->query("UPDATE user SET IMAGE='$name' WHERE id='".$idf."'")) {echo $mysql->error;}else{};
  }
  else echo 'Error';
 }
}
}
else echo "Session not found";
?>
```

Comment: Вам может проще нанять человека, или прочесть пару книжек? у вас что ни вопрос то яркий пример "как вопросы задавать не стоит" =)
Где хоть одна попытка подумать?)) Хоть один свой пример кода....

Answer (score 0):

получите данные из БД

`SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=?`

в столбце "IMAGE" у вас хранится путь к картинке, используйте его в html или где-то еще)