# Формирование ссылок на картинки в БД

Tags: php

Есть код, с помощью которого я загружаю картинки в БД и на хостинг, но как мне записывать в БД именно ссылки на картинки? Чтобы потом достать их

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $sesion_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $idf = ($_SESSION['userid']);

if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
if(empty($_FILES['file']['size']))  die('Вы не выбрали файл');
if($_FILES['file']['size'] > (5 * 1024 * 1024)) die('image size <5mb');
$imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$arr = array('image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png');
if(!in_array($imageinfo['mime'],$arr)) echo ('image format');
 else {

$upload_dir = '/public_html/img/avatars'; 

$name = date('YmdHis').basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

$mov = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$name);
  if($mov) {

$name = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($name)));
 if(!$mysqli->query("UPDATE user SET IMAGE='$name' WHERE id='".$idf."'")) {echo $mysql->error;}else{};
  }
  else echo 'Error';
 }
}
}
else echo "Session not found";
?>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вытащить картинку из БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883402/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%91%d0%94)

Answer (score 0):

В этом нет ничего сложного: 
Просто сохраните в базу данных путь до файла в том формате как вам удобно.
Например, если вы будете выводить ссылки на изображение от корня сайта и папка public_html лежит в корневой дирректории сайта, то у вас должна быть ссылка вида `public_html/img/avatars/filename.jpg`

Конкретно в вашем случае сохраняйте в бд следующее:
`$upload_dir.$name`

Только ваш способ задания имени файла не гарантирует уникальность. Посудите сами: вероятность того что в данный конкретный момент времени несколько пользователей зальют файл с одинаковым именем - очень высока.

Comment: а не могли бы помочь с директорией загрузки, ну т.е я не использую $upload_dir по назначению, и получается что у меня все файлы льются в public_html

Comment: @Midnight, сформулируйте вопрос точнее, я не понимаю чего именно вы хотие добиться

Comment: как мне в моем коде изменить путь сохранения файлов на хостинге?

Comment: @Midnight за путь у вас отвечает переменная `$upload_dir`. За имя файла  - переменная `$name`.  Путь файлу должен состоять из конкатенации этих двух переменных, т.е. `$upload_dir.$name`. Собственно результ этой конкатенации вы и должны сохранить в БД.
Что уж вы пропишете в переменную `$upload_dir` -  это ваша воля, в зависимости от того какую дирректорию вы хотите ипользовать.
Например если у меня в корне сайте лежит папка `img`, я бы сохранял так: `img/avatars/filename.jpg`, и выводил так `<img src = "img/avatars/filename.jpg" >`

Comment: что-то я совсем запутался, вы не могли бы привести код, как должно быть? пожалуйста